# Проводник не адаптироваться под панель C# Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form, explorer

Есть панель и кнопка. По кнопке я открываю и запускаю процесс(приложение). И оно должно масштабироваться под панель, чтобы не можно было двигать приложения. Проблема в том , что проводник не масштабируется в панель и всегда выдает ошибку в SetParent. Может кто знает ,из-за чего проводник не масштабируется под панель ? Проверял на других приложениях айтюнс , тим вьювер ,паинт. Они все масштабируются под панель.[image: Вот такую ошибку выдает]

Comment: Проводник - это окно рабочего стола, это не приложение, его нельзя подчинить себе как процесс. Запускаемый explorer сообщает своей главной копии (рабочему столу), что надо сделать, и сразу завершается. Поэтому вам и выскакивает ошибка, что процесс завершен. Возможно вам следует искать Handle этого окна другими способами, например через WinAPI, а не через `Process`.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за ответ ) Сейчас буду пробовать )